# Resolve Proper URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I turn domain.com into https://www.domain.com (the actual address)? Is there an easy API for this?

The purpose is to allow a user to enter a domain in preferences and allow my app to convert that into a fully qualified web URL like a web browser does when I type google.com it returns http://www.google.com (ish).

Comment: Can you explain further what you're trying to do? I mean, on the face of it you're trying to magically create a more specific domain ("place.domain.com") from a less specific one ("domain.com"), which isn't possible barring some external information (e.g., "place").

Comment: Please give more information.  In particular, what is it about domain.com that suggests that the "actual address" should be "www.place.domain.com"?  Would "stackoverflow.com" get turned into "www.place.stackoverflow.com"?  What do you mean by "actual address"?

Comment: Sorry place.domain didn't make sence >.<
I updated the question.

Comment: why are you going to https://www.domain.com (note the https)?  What if there should not be a www?

Comment: place.domain.com directs me to https://place.domain.com:00000 (port number). How can I get my app to give me that address as a string is my question. I want to say NSURLConnection should be able to give me that address but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @S-T-R-E-G-A: "want to say NSURLConnection should be able to give me that address but I can't figure it out"  Please UPDATE your question.  Please add **specific** questions you have about `NSURLConnection`.  Please UPDATE your question to be specific.

Comment: Also, note that http: //domain.com and http: //www.domain.com are not necessarily the same thing, it is more by convention than by any enforcement that this is usually true.  One or both might not even respond, if the webserver is only configured to answer to one domainname or the other.

Answer (score 2):

If typing *your domain*.com results in https://www.*your domain*.com then the server is redirecting. Here is a rule to follow:

- Construct "`https://`*domain the user typed*". Connect to that, and follow any 301 (permanent) redirects until you get a 200 response. Save the URL you end up at as the permanent one.
- If your connection failed, try again with `http://` instead of `https://`.

Do not assume that the "proper" URL contains "`www.`"; if it should, then the server will redirect.

Answer (score 0):

What's so hard about putting "http://www." in front?

How does that require an API?

Are you asking about the string concatenation API?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`NSURL`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURL) class. More specifically, use [`initWithScheme:host:path`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJIGJIG) where scheme is "http", host is your string and path is empty.